# Issue with code continuing?

Tags: python

I wrote this, and for some reason after I get to the point of asking what month it is, it doesn't go any further. I'll type in a month and the code will just end.

```
    year = input("What year is it?")
    if year == "1996":
input ("What month is it?")
    month = "January"
    elif month == ["January","Febuary", "March"]:
input == ("How much snow fell that month?")
```

Any help would be great

Comment: Post some more of your code to interact with, if you could

Comment: and please fix your indentation - it is critical in python, and we can't help you if the code you post wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `input("What month is it?")` needs to be assigned to a variable.

Ex: `month = input("What month is it?")`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is Python3, the return value from `input` can never be a list containing three different month names. You probably mean

```
elif month in ['January', 'February', 'March']:
    snow= input(...)
```

Notice also how `input == ('...')` is not what you want, and whimsically pointless.

Finally, like @TravisJacobs notes, you need to capture the month name input.

```
month = input('What month is it?')
```

It's not clear if `month = 'January'` should only happen if `year` is not 1996; then, you need to put it in an `else:` clause.